# How to simulate double clicking item in qlistWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

How can I simulate double clicking an item in a `QListWidget` without sub-classing? I would like the item to immediately go into edit mode when I add a new item to the list.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't the `void QListWidget::editItem ( QListWidgetItem * item )` the proper method for this?

Comment: Thank you much. I hadn't noticed this function. this is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add a double click functionality

```
connect(ui->listWidget,SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(on_dbclick_play()));
```

where `on_dbclick_play()` is the function you want to invoke while double clicked.